# Applying Conditions on Pandas DataFrame Columns before reading csv or tsv files

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

Is it possible to set conditions (filters) for the DataFrame columns before reading a csv or tsv files, If I am already aware of the column names and types? If yes, how?

For Example: Consider there are two numerical columns (col1 and col2) in a very big file. I do not want to load whole file in the memory and select only those rows where col1 greater than col2. Therefore, first, I want to set the condition on the dataframe that it should read only those rows from the csv file where col1 is greater than col2. I hope my explanation make sense.

Thanks

Comment: Your question is too vague because it depends on what the filtering involves, post a representative sample of data and the desired output

Comment: What type of filters?  I do not believe you can filter data while reading it in Pandas.  You would need to use the CSV reader, filter the data as your read each row, and then create a dataframe from the filtered rows.

Comment: @EdChum. Consider there are two numerical columns (col1 and col2) in a very big file. I do not want to load whole file in the memory and select only those rows where col1 greater than col2. Therefore, first, I want to set the condition on the dataframe that it should read only those rows where col1 is greater than col2. I hope my explanation make sense

Comment: Please edit your question with the new updated details, based on your updated requirements yes it can be done. Can you show your efforts

Comment: @EdChum my code is reading the file chunk by chunk (http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/io.html#iterating-through-files-chunk-by-chunk) and applying the conditions. However, that is not what I am looking for.

Comment: If you want to apply a condition on the data you read in you first need to read the data to apply the condition and by that alone the data will be in your memory, necessarily. So even if you could set a dataframe to not accept certain data based on that condition, the data will be written into your memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [blaze](https://blaze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for this which is a handy tool to have alongside `pandas`.

Let's assume an input file of:

```
a,b
1,2
3,4
5,3
3,6
6,1
```

We then open the file and query the data - note that the query isn't executed until you attempt to materialise/access it:

```
import blaze
import pandas as pd

csv_data = blaze.Data('input.csv')
query = csv_data[csv_data['a'] > csv_data['b']]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(query, columns=query.fields)
```

That then gives `df` as:

```
   a  b
0  5  3
1  6  1
```

Comment: Doesn't blaze load whole csv data in the memory?

Comment: @Manu nope - it loads into memory the rows that pass the query and it only does that as part of the construction of the DataFrame...

Comment: As of today, Blaze isn't compatible with Pandas anymore because Pandas changed `pd.tslib.NaTType` to `type(pd.NaT)`. It was patched in [#546](https://github.com/blaze/odo/pull/546) but it seems like no one is including the patch in the new releases. The  build and doc have been broken for several months indicating the development has stalled.

Is there an alternative to Blaze ?