# How to load only specific kind of rows into pandas dataframe to avoid memory overloading

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe 91gb and when I try to load it into memory to work with it -  I get memory crush. Is it possible to load for example only where  m.0107_f index rows out of all data into Pandas Dataframe and don't load full data into dataframe?

The example of my dataset is:

[image]

Something what I want to do -

```
df = pd.read_csv('/Volumes/big-flash-drive/asdf/FaceImageCroppedWithAlignment.tsv', sep='\t', nrows='m.0107_f', 
             names = ["Freebase MID", "EntityNameString", "ImageURL", "FaceID","FaceRectangle_Base64Encoded",
                       "FaceData_Base64Encoded"])
```

I understand that this is unlikely but maybe someone can help to deal with it

Comment: You should check out [this incredible answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39351962/1577947) by Jon Clements. His suggestion is to use [blaze](https://blaze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: thanks for all your help

Answer (score 0):

Try the following approach if you have to work with CSV files:

```
fn = '/Volumes/big-flash-drive/asdf/FaceImageCroppedWithAlignment.tsv'
cols = ["Freebase MID","EntityNameString","ImageURL", "FaceID",
        "FaceRectangle_Base64Encoded","FaceData_Base64Encoded"]
chunks = pd.read_csv(fn, sep='\t', chunksize=10**5, names=cols)
df = pd.concat([x.query("index == 'm.0107_f'") for x in chunks], ignore_index=True)
```

If you can store your data in different format - i would strongly recommend you to use HDF5 format or to store your data in RDBMS DB:

Demo:

```
df = pd.read_hdf('/path/to/file.h5', 'hdf_key', where="index == 'm.0107_f'")
```

this will read up only those rows that satisfy `where` clause

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try 
Btw, I got this error after trying ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: out of memory.

Answer (score 0):

```
import blaze
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

# using StringIO for demonstration-purposes! Don't actually do this in your code!
# your code would look like: data = blaze.data('myfile.csv') 
s = '''idx,MID,S,A
m.0107_f,a,1,True
m.0107_x,b,2,False
m.0107_f,c,3,True'''
data = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s))
```

`data` looks like:

```
        idx MID  S      A
0  m.0107_f   a  1   True
1  m.0107_x   b  2  False
2  m.0107_f   c  3   True
```

Now blaze:

```
csv_data = blaze.data(data)
csv_data[csv_data['idx'] == 'm.0107_f']
```

Result:

```
        idx MID  S     A
0  m.0107_f   a  1  True
2  m.0107_f   c  3  True
```

The benefit here is that using blaze only loads items in memory that meet the condition (being equivalent to `m.0107_f`).